# Setting linker preferences for multiple shared libraries of same name

Tags: c++, linux, linker

I link my application against multiple shared libraries, one of which is Google's gRPC, which in turn links against boringSSL. I also link against other libraries, which in turn link against OpenSSL. In the end, calling `ldd` on my binary and grepping for ssl gives:

```
    libssl.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f62f35c8000)
    libssl.so => /usr/local/grpc/lib/libssl.so (0x00007f62f28b6000)
```

I would rather not statically link against gRPC and friends. Is there a way I can set preferences that the second result should be used for gRPC only and the first for everything else?

I am using CMake as a build project, if that helps.

Comment: You can research if in gRPC there is a way to build it by statically linking it to boringSSL. Then, you should be able to link against other libraries including gRPC dynamically.

Comment: I did. There seems to be no such option. Also, I cited an example to make things relatable, but the goal is to search for a generic solution, not a gRPC specific one.

Comment: Although I am not sure how it would cause problems, because the symbols defined in OpenSSL and boringSSL should have different names. If they have different names, there should be no collisions during linking.

Comment: boringSSL is a forked and patched version of OpenSSL. They are not API compatible. But nowhere does it say that the names of all existing symbols were changed. If you see such a document, please share. In my experience, the differences are relatively sublte, like how error handling is done.

Comment: Hmm, so they have same symbols. And by these "other libraries" you probably mean libraries like curl?

Comment: For example, yes :)